Force calculation exercise
I'm a student working on a problem, and I'm struggling with part (d), which asks: 'What is the maximum angle?' I know the answer should be 40 degrees, but my solution gives 46.67. I'd really appreciate any help you can offer."
the question:

A 20 N block is placed on an inclined plane with a rough surface.
The incline angle is 30 degrees above the horizontal, and the coefficient of static friction is 0.84.

Questions:
a. Calculate the direction of the friction force acting on the block.
b. Draw a force diagram showing the forces acting on the block.
c. Calculate the magnitude of the friction force.
d. What is the maximum angle at which the block can remain stationary on the incline without sliding?
my calculates:


step one is "40 what?"

Welcome to Physics.SE Maya. You haven't explained how you obtained the solution that appears to be incorrect. On this site one has to show his work in order to be helped (and do it via MathJax, not pictures).

Good demonstration of your effort. Note that the friction force that you calculated is only for a 30-degree slope, and not for all slopes. Therefore, in your final calculations you cannot equate that force with $w\sin\alpha$. Can you take it from here?

Your mistake is forgetting that your calculation of $fs_{max}$ depends on the angle of the plane. So in part (d) you cannot assume that $fs_{max} = 14.549$ N because that value is specific to a 30 degree angle. You need to use the general expression $fs_{max} = \mu N = 20 \mu \cos \gamma$ when the plane is at an angle $\gamma$ to the horizontal.
